# How to multiply a single element of a column with entire row in a table in ms-access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design, ms-office

I am trying to make an inventory management system for a bakery using MS Access.
The shop manager will enter only the name and quantity of the item that they wish to make. Based on the items entered by the manager, a list of ingredients and their quantities should be generated in a systematic manner.
For example,
To make one cake 2 x ingredient A, 3 x ingredient B and 4 x ingredient C are required. 
And for one cookie, we will need 0.1 x ingredient C and 1 x ingredient D.
If the manager wishes to make 2 Cakes and 5 Cookies, the amount of each ingredient must be calculated and presented in a report.

I have tried making separate tables for list of Items and another table which holds the ingredients required to make a particular item. But I am not sure how to match the item from list of Items table with the table corresponding to the table which contains it's ingredients list.

Comment: This is more a design issue, not programming, and not appropriate question for SO.

Comment: You will need a 3rd table for the products (item + number). For the calculation you then JOIN all 3 tables. For more help you'll need to show us your table structure and sample data. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: If you know some VBA, you could code something. You just need a standard record for 1 item. SQL would get the ingredients of that item a,d then with VBA you could easily multiply each field of that record by the number of desired items.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use something EAV (entity, attribute, value) approach for this.

[image]

Then you could use this query to get list of ingridients for definite order (with corresponding amounts)

```
    SELECT tblIngridients.sIngridientName, Sum(tblReceipts.fIngridientAmount) AS [Sum-fIngridientAmount]
FROM (tblProducts INNER JOIN tblOrderContents ON tblProducts.iProductID = tblOrderContents.iProductID) INNER JOIN (tblIngridients INNER JOIN tblReceipts ON tblIngridients.iIngridientID = tblReceipts.iIngridientID) ON tblProducts.iProductID = tblReceipts.iProductID
WHERE (((tblOrderContents.iOrderID)=1))
GROUP BY tblIngridients.sIngridientName;
```

[image]

Comment: I think, for OP's use case, Products and Receipts should be one table, not two. Apart from that: spot on.

Comment: @Van Ng sir, thanks for the reply. Can you please share your .accdb file?

Comment: my email ID: [link](mailto:ravirao@ieee.org)

Comment: you can download it here - https://ufile.io/v9b02qk6